# What's the meaning of "shred thoughts"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Could you tell me what the meaning of **shredding my thoughts** is in the following context?

The complete phrase is

> I had only a few seconds to wonder why before the needles returned,
>   shredding my thoughts

It's included in this text:

> I AWOKE WITH NEEDLES in my brain. Thousands of them, biting, blocking out
>   everything. Then they disappeared for one dizzying moment and I got my
>   bearings.
>   It was morning, early; amber sunlight poured in through my bedroom
>   window. I was standing but not on my own strength. Two hands were
>   gripping my throat, and they’d been shaking me. The needles, that was my
>   brain crashing into my skull. *I had only a few seconds to wonder why
>   before the needles returned*, **shredding my thoughts**. My eyes were open
>   but I saw only white flashes. A few sounds made it through to me.
>   “SLUT!”
>   “WHORE!”
>   Then another sound. Mother. She was crying. “Stop! You’re killing her!
>   Stop!”

*Educated* by Tara Westover

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles/shred)

**to shred**

> to cut or tear something roughly into thin strips

It's a metaphor. She got only seconds to wonder because the pain caused by the needles didn't let she think. Her thoughts were **shredded**, abruptly interrupted by the pain.

EDITED due to OP's doubts - Taken from @Andrew's comment:

***needles*** is a common metaphor to describe a severe sharp, stabbing pain. **Pins** would be less intense (because pins are shorter than needles). You will also see "pins and needles" to describe the sensation of something like when your foot starts to "wake up" after it "falls asleep" (from lack of blood flow)

Comment: Could you please tell me "the needle" is a metaphor too, Or is a real thing?

Comment: @Peace I think that it's a methaphor too, no real needles were being inserted in her skull. "Then they disappeared for one dizzying moment"

Comment: @Peace But I can't no be sure, if she is trapped in some sort of hospital facility and someone is torturing her, they may be real needles. Keep reading.

Comment: No she is in her own room. And what about the "The needles, that was my brain crashing into my skull."? Could you please rewrite it?

Comment: @Peace I think that she may have a migraine, "a recurrent throbbing headache"

Comment: @Peace when her brother dragged her through the room and threw her to the ground, she most likely hit her head. "the needles" is the pain she's experiencing, speaking metaphorically again. She goes on to describe that it's not a common headache but rather her brain physically hurting due to the impact.

Comment: @Peace "needles" is a common metaphor to describe a severe sharp, stabbing pain.  "Pins" would be less intense (because *pins* are shorter than *needles*).  You will also see "pins and needles" to describe the sensation of something like when your foot starts to "wake up" after it "falls asleep" (from lack of blood flow)

Comment: @Andrew the structure of the two sentences are quite strange to me. Can you help to explain them a bit? "*The needles, that was my brain crashing into my skull. I had only a few seconds to wonder why before the needles returned, shredding my thoughts. *"

Comment: @dan "needles" is the metaphor the author uses to describe her pain.  Just substitute in "the pain" and it should make sense, *"the pain, that was my brain crashing into my skull"*

Comment: @Andrew "the pain, that was my brain crashing into my skull " doesn't look like a full sentence. I am not sure how to parse it. What are the subject, predicate and object?

Comment: @dan English writers will often ignore "proper" grammar and sentence structure in order to create an effect.  In this case the sentence is likely *purposefully* jumbled to give an impression of what the narrator was going through.  To make it a "proper" sentence, remove "that", *"The pain was (the result of) my brain crashing into my skull"*

Comment: @dan there are so many creative ways writers can manipulate the language for effect that I could not possibly give examples of all of them.  The best thing to do is to read as much as possible and get used to different writer's *styles*.  Side note: I don't think much of this particular writer's style.  To me it seems overly dramatic, among other problems.   But that's really up to individual taste.

Comment: @Andrew I am also not sure the structure of *......why before the needles returned, shredding my thoughts.* can you help to explain a little bit on that too? Thank you very much!

Comment: @dan if you like please ask this as a question?  We're getting into extended comments, and it's a lot easier if I can write it out in the answer box.

Comment: @Andrew I just did it. You can review it now. Thanks!